# Deleting with rm did not free up space

Tags: macos, command-line, trash

I deleted a 5gb video using rm video.mp4, but the space hasn't freed.

This was the situation: while encoding a video with FCP X, I ran out of space, I only had 50 MB free. Since in the trash I had some stuff that I wasn't sure that I could delete it yet, I took the terminal and I manually deleted a big video file with `rm video.mp4`.

The file is gone, but the main problem is that the disk is still full. What I can do to reclaim this space back?

It's normal that manually deleting a file will not free up space?

Comment: You can force time machine to purge copies of files that are changed and deleted with the command `sudo tmutil disablelocal`

Comment: Time machine is disabled

Answer (score 1):

Probably your file is in use by some process, in this case it's normal. Try to close or kill apps or processes that used that file.

Comment: Good answer if you could add how to find out what process are using the file.

Comment: @Buscar웃 you can use the terminal to track files  using: "tail -F 'PATH OF UR FILE'  hope this finds you

Comment: one way to see which process uses which file is the "lsof" command

Comment: The precise command to find which processes have a file open is `sudo lsof` but this is far more likely to be time machine local backups keeping a copy of the deleted file until the space gets so low as to require a purge of the oldest backed up files.